# Launch application from alert view of push notification

Tags: iphone

How can i launch my application when user taps the view button in the alert that came due to push notification?

Comment: ? The the user taps "view" your app will be launched whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens automatically. When the user taps the "View" button, your application will launch and your application delegate will receive the `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. If your application's already running and in the background, I believe it receives the `-application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` message, probably just after it gets `-applicationWillEnterForeground:`.